# c# + autocad mirror command

Tags: c#, autocad

```
var commandString = string.Format("_.mirror _C\r{0}\r{1}\r {2}\r{3} _n\r",
                pEnd.ToString2D(), pStart.ToString2D(), axialPStart.ToString2D(), axialPEnd.ToString2D());
            _acadCurrentDocument.SendCommand(commandString);
```

does not work, i believe it is because \r.
How to pass trough this situation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Autocad, but does the `\r` denote a carriage return or is it part of the syntax? If the latter, try adding `@` at the beginning of the string. `@"_.mirror _C\r{0}\r{1}\r {2}\r{3} _n\r"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an AutoCAD handy to test here, but I believe `\r` alone is not recognized by the command interpreter as a press on the `ENTER` key. Try using `\n` instead:

```
"_.mirror _C\n{0}\n{1}\n {2}\n{3} _n\n"
```

Comment: @d.lebedev, can you post the details of the exception you receive?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the spaces in your expression with \r and check that osmode is at zero because the two points of your capture can be the same